# Подключение css шрифтов локально

Tags: html, css, шрифты, web-fonts

Искал в интернете , как подключить шрифты к сайту, с ссылкой на локальный файл, но полного ответа нигде не нашел
Объясните пожалуйста по пунктам и в полном объеме, что нужно сделать, чтобы подключить шрифты к html и css файлам

Comment: Так уж и не нашли? )) http://htmlbook.ru/blog/svoi-shrift-na-stranitse

Answer (score 1):

1. Находите или создаете файлы шрифтов (в разных форматах, для кросс-браузерности). Например, у вас шрифт "Шо-то-там" - вам понадобятся файлы шрифта. Кладете их в папку, например, /your-site/fonts. Получаете в ней такой набор файлов:

   - st-Regular.ttf
   - st-Italic.ttf
   - st-Bold.ttf
   - st-Regular.woff
   - st-Italic.woff
   - st-Bold.woff
2. Создаете в css-файле столько директив @font-face, сколько файлов шрифтов у вас задействуется:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Shototam';
  src: url(/yoursite/fonts/st-Regular.ttf) format('ttf'), url(/yoursite/fonts/st-Regular.woff) format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Shototam';
  src: url(/yoursite/fonts/st-Italic.ttf) format('ttf'), url(/yoursite/fonts/st-Italic.woff) format('woff');
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Shototam';
  src: url(/yoursite/fonts/st-Bold.ttf) format('ttf'), url(/yoursite/fonts/st-Bold.woff) format('woff');
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

3. Применяете в стилях нужных элементов свойство `font-family`, указав "затычку" на случай неподгружения файлов шрифта:

   .my_bold_element {
        font-family:Shototam,Sans-serif,Arial;
        font-weight:bold;
   }